# Java : How can we further simplify the java 8 streams logic for Files

Tags: java, file, java-stream, simplify

**How can we combine the 2 streams logic present below :**

```
public void filterRecord(File inputDirectory) throws IOException {

        if (inputDirectory.exists() && !inputDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            List<Path> pathStreams = Files.list(Paths.get(inputDirectory.getAbsolutePath()))
                    .filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".csv"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            for (Path filePath : pathStreams) {

                Files.lines(filePath)
                        .filter(line -> (line != null && !line.isEmpty()))
                        .filter(line -> "10".equals(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(",")).trim()))
                        .forEach(System.out::println);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the above code, the two Streams are taking part,

1. First stream is filter the file list with particular extention using the directory path.
2. Second stream is filter the content from the file and print on console.

Comment: ...`.flatMap(filePath -> Files.lines(filePath)).` would have been easier... but you can't, unless you create a method that handles and doesn't throw `IOException` further. Something like `try {
                            return Files.lines(path);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return Stream.empty(); // or a RuntimeException
                        }`

Comment: First, why are you working with `File` at all? Word directly with paths. Make the method signature a `Path`. There is barely any need to use `java.io.File` in 2020. Second, please research the `flatMap` operation on streams.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void fileStreamsFilter(Path inputDirectoryPath) throws IOException {

    if (Files.exists(inputDirectoryPath) && Files.isDirectory(inputDirectoryPath)) {

        Files.list(inputDirectoryPath).filter(path -> path.toString().endsWith(".csv"))
        .flatMap(path -> {
            try {
                return Files.lines(path);
            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                log.error(ioException.getMessage(), ioException);
            }
            return null;
        })
        .filter(line -> (line != null && !line.isEmpty()))
        .filter(line -> "10".equals(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(",")).trim()))
        .forEach(log::info);
    }
}
```